# Orbifold and covering orbifold

Tags: orbifolds

I've seen that the chart mapping diagram commutes for different quotient mapping in some textbooks. Thus I am wondering whether one orbifold ($O$) derived from a (normal) subgroup ($S \lhd G$) can be regarded as its covering orbifold, namely the other orbifold derived from super-group $G$ ($O'=M/G$) would be the quotient orbifolds of $O$.

Is this statement correct? If so, is it the property in commutative diagram vital in this statement? Does the subgroup need to be a normal subgroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in orbifolds, while you can still check some previous articles and answers as inspiration. Some concept in "*regular*" covering map will also help, since deck transformation from another normal subgroup $H \lhd G$ will induce another regular covering.

[1]Choi, S. (2012). Manifolds and $\mathcal {G} $-structures. In Geometric Structures on 2-Orbifolds: Exploration of Discrete Symmetry . Mathematical Society of Japan.